# recode data function other data

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I want to recodate my data, function of decisions rules

An example of rules :

Data with more than 3 variables years

First rule  :we corrected data  if only one error :
y ≤ y+2 and y+1 < y then y+1 = y

After the previous correction,  corrected with the second rule :

- More than 2 identical years, keep the most frequent
- Equality of frequencies : keep the higher

Maybe with an example it's little bit more clear :

```
ID  y1  y2  y3   y4 y5
1   6   7   6   8   
2   6   7   7   6   8
3   6   7   8   7   8
4   6   7   8   6   7
6   3   4   5   6   3
```

the corrected data

```
ID  y1  y2  y3   y4 y5
1   6   7   7   8   
2   6   7   7   7   8
3   6   7   8   8   8
4   6   7   7   7   7
6   3   4   5   6   3
```

If you have any idea to corrected variable function of other variable, many thank's

---

If I have an ID with 8 years of data, line 4 doesn't work. Do you know why ? It's problem with a lot of NA?
Before code :

```
ID  y1 y2  y3   y4  y5  y6  y7  y8
1   6   7   6   8   NA  NA  NA  NA
2   6   7   7   6   8   NA  NA  NA
3   6   7   8   7   8   NA  NA  NA
4   6   7   8   6   7   NA  NA  NA
5   3   4   5   6   3   NA  NA  NA
6   7   7   8   8   7   8   7   8
```

after code

```
   y1  y2  y3  y4   y5  y6  y7  y8
1   6   7   7   8   NA  NA  NA  NA
2   6   7   7   7   8   NA  NA  NA
3   6   7   8   8   8   NA  NA  NA
4   6   7   8   6   7   NA  NA  NA
5   3   4   5   6   3   NA  NA  NA
6   7   7   8   8   8   8   8   8
```

If you have a solution otherwise I will make a select according to the number of non empty fields

Comment: if  y = y1 then y+2= y3   but if y=y2 , y+2=y4 .....

Comment: row 4 the rule More than 2 identical years, keep the most frequent and row2 the same rule like raw1 (rule1) y3 ≤ y5 and y4 < y2 then y4 = y3

Comment: excuse me, I do a mistake the Rule :Equality of frequencies : keep the higher

Comment: We never change y1.

Comment: Yes you could omit y1. I will look in detail results to see the overlapping conditions

Comment: I made a slight modification to my solution so that problem with row 4 of the second data set with 8 `y` values has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Solution**
I made a slight modification so that it can be used for with observations containing `NA` values:

- I used `pmap_df` function from `purrr` package that is used for row-wise operation on data frames as you can pass multiple arguments into it
- `c(...)` captures all values of `y` in each row except the value of `ID` which I omitted by `c(...)[-1]`
- For your `y + 2` I omitted the first two values of every row since they cannot be `y + 2` and since we are also checking `y + 1` for every `y` the length of two expressions must be the same. So I only chose those `y + 1` where there is a `y + 2`
- With regard to other rules I created a vector called `z` which only requires to omit `y1` from `x` and check if there are 3 unique values meaning 2 are the same then transform all others to that value

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  pmap_df(~ {x <- c(...)[!is.na(c(...))][-1]
  y_2 <- x[-c(1, 2)]
  y_1 <- x[2:(length(y_2) + 1)]
  ids <- which((x[seq_along(y_2)] <= y_2) & (y_1 < x[seq_along(y_1)]))
  x[ids + 1] <- x[ids]
  x
  z <- x[-1]
  if(length(unique(z)) == 3 & sum(is.na(z)) == 0) {
    z[1:length(z)] <- z[duplicated(z)]
    c(x[1], z)
  } else {
    c(x[1], z)
  }})

# A tibble: 5 x 5
     y1    y2    y3    y4    y5
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     6     7     7     8    NA
2     6     7     7     7     8
3     6     7     8     8     8
4     6     7     7     7     7
5     3     4     5     6     3
```

Second data sample

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
     y1    y2    y3    y4    y5    y6    y7    y8
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     6     7     7     8    NA    NA    NA    NA
2     6     7     7     7     8    NA    NA    NA
3     6     7     8     8     8    NA    NA    NA
4     6     7     7     7     7    NA    NA    NA
5     3     4     5     6     3    NA    NA    NA
6     7     7     8     8     8     8     8     8
```

Comment: Thank you. It's possible to explain a little bit your code so I can complete it with my other rules.

Comment: Sure, some edits might be need for rule 2 and 3 but so far it gives your desired results. I will add some notes now.

Comment: Check my updates please and let me know if I need to explain more.

Comment: thank you for explanations. the line with ids is to be sur we have more than 3 variables y. And many thanks for the code and the quickness.